# How can i send nessus log over syslog?

Tags: redhat, syslog, nessus

I've been ask to send the logs from a Nessus scanner remotely on a syslog server,
But I can't find a way to bind it to syslog.

Is there a way to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use the **imfile** module of rsyslog and configure a rule for each Nessus log file.

Here's a suggestion on how to proceed:

1. Edit */etc/rsyslog.conf*
2. Add the following line:
   $ModLoad imfile
3. Create the imfile rules by adding the below lines for each log file (I suggest including *nessusd.messages*, *nessusd.dump* and *backend.log*. By default, they are in */opt/nessus/var/nessus/logs*):

   **# File 1

   $InputFileName path_to_file

   $InputFileTag tag:

   $InputFileStateFile state_file_name

   $InputRunFileMonitor**
4. Restart Rsyslog

There are more optional settings available but the aforementioned ones are required. Refer to the ["Using Rsyslog Modules"](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System_Administrators_Guide/s1-using_rsyslog_modules.html) RedHat guide for more info.

Note that you can also configure these rules in a separate file. Should you choose to do so, you'll need to add the ***$IncludeConfig*** directive in */etc/rsyslog.conf/*. See the [Rsyslog documentation](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/rsconf1_includeconfig.html).

.